# Facebook App Sending PUSH Notifications

Tags: php, facebook

I have an app built that stores users' fbids. Client has asked to send push notifications to these users every day. Can someone outline the steps I need to use the Facebook API for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applications can generate notifications by issuing a HTTP POST request to the /user_id/notifications Graph API, with a app access_token.

`POST /{recipient_userid}/notifications?access_token= … &template= … &href= …`

You can find more useful information here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-notifications/

Comment: Where does POST go to? I am using curl in an external site. I have generated the access token and got the href and template done but am at a loss.

Comment: It should probably POST to https://graph.facebook.com//{recipient_userid}/notifications. You can find more details about the graph API here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/